# Why is my WCF Help Page only displaying GET methods?

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, iis

I have a WCF REST Service with the following contract hosted in a WCF Service application :

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method="GET", 
        RequestFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json,
        ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json,
        UriTemplate="key/{key}")]
    Task<string> GetDocumentInDefaultBucket(string key);

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        UriTemplate = "bucket/{bucket}/key/{key}")]
    Task<string> GetDocument(string bucket, string key);

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle= WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
        UriTemplate = "doc")]
    Task<bool> InsertDocumentInDefaultBucket(string doc);

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "PUT",
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
        UriTemplate = "udoc")]
    Task<bool> UpdateDocumentInDefaultBucket(string doc);
}
```

However, only the GET methods are displayed in the WCF Help Page :

[image: WCF Help Page]

I have no service explicitely defined in the configuration file, I've just added the following code to the application_start event :

```
RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("", new WebServiceHostFactory(), typeof(Service)));
```

Any help appreciated.

**UPDATE 1** : The very same project works like a charm on other similar development environment.

**UPDATE 2** : OMG ! It works on IIS
[image: WCF Help Page]

Answer (score 0):

In the Web.config file add the System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule module and set the runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests attribute to true. Also add the UrlRoutingHandler handler to the  element as shown below.

```
  <system.webServer>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
  <add name="UrlRoutingModule" 
    type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, 
          Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
</modules>
<handlers>
  <add name="UrlRoutingHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="UrlRouting.axd"/>
</handlers>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have mixed couple of things. Here's a quick info about the WebGet and WebInvoke. 
`WebGet` stands for HttpGet operations.
`WebInvoke` stands for Post requests E.g. `HTTP PUT`, `HTTP DELETE` and `HTTP POST` operations.

You have only used the WebInvoke for both type of Operations.Try correcting those attributions and see if that works. Next, you have `ResponseFormat attribute` missing in Post methods. It might be the case if your configuration is only supporting Json and default formatter(in this case it could be XmlFormatter) is suppressing it to show on help page.

If this doesn't work kindly add your Endpoint configurations and Any other custom configurations done in the source code.

Comment: I've decided to test the same project on two of my co-worker machines and it works like a charm in both cases ! The problem seems definitely tied to my environment.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm confused...

hit CRTL+F5 in Internet Explorer and it works. The navigator was keeping an old version in it's cache.